# How to set up a serial port in VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox, serial-port

I need to access a serial device in my VirtualBox guest (Windows XP).  My host system is ArchLinux 64-bit.  I configured the VirtualBox serial port as follows:

- Port:     COM1
- IRQ:     4
- I/O Port: 0x3F8
- Port Path: `/dev/ttyS0`

Now, I am pretty certain it is `/dev/ttyS0` as when I do a `cat` or `echo` to/from the device, I get nothing. Whereas, with the other paths, I get input/output errors.

I don't believe it is a permissions issue as I belong to the uucp group which is the owning group of the device.

Any ideas what I can try?

Comment: I also ran VirtualBox as root and was unable to connect my serial device as expected.